# Renderizar una lista ordenado por fecha desde un objeto en React Js

Tags: javascript, array, json, reactjs

Estoy tratando de renderizar una array de objetos de partidos, cada partido tiene una fecha, lo que quiero es mostrar la fecha como titulo y seguido los partidos correspondientes a esa fecha, luego continuar con las demás fechas.

***Date_match:** Desde la BD viene como un **string** con formato **Año/Mes/Dia**, pero en la BD es de tipo **Date***

Este es el código de la lista de partidos. El componente Match simplemente muestra los detalles del partido.

```
const MatchList = () => {

    const matchs = useMatch()
    
    return (
       <div>
          <h1 className=''>Match List</h1>
          {matchs.map((m) => (
              <div>
                  <h1>{m.date_match}</h1>
                  <Match key={m.id} matchDetails={m} />
              </div>
           
          ))}
       </div>
   )
}
```

Este es el resultado de mi código hasta ahora.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta imagen muestra como quiero se vea la lista de partidos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es el campo `date_match`?

Comment: Desde la BD viene como un string con formato Año/Mes/Dia, pero en la BD es de tipo Date

Comment: Ok, entonces a tu JS ya llega como un string, es correcto?

Comment: Si, es correcto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes de hacer es agrupar los partidos por fecha. Esto puedes hacerlo usando un diccionario, y dado que la fecha de los partidos es un `String`, puedes ocupar dicho `String` como la llave de cada entrada del diccionario.

El diccionario estaría compuesto por la fecha como llave, y un arreglo como el valor a guardar. Dicho arreglo contendrá cada uno de los partidos que se llevan a cabo en dicha fecha.

Una vez que ya estén agrupados, iteras las llaves del diccionario, para que puedas usar la fecha/llave como el título, y posteriormente, haces una iteración del valor de esa llave en el diccionario, es decir, el arreglo donde están agrupados todos los partidos en una misma fecha.

```
const MatchList = () => {

    const matchs = useMatch()

    const matchsDictionary = {}

    // Crea un diccionario donde la llave sea la fecha y
    // el valor un array vavció para guardar los partidos.
    for (let i = 0; i < matchs.length; ++i)
        matchsDictionary[matchs[i].date_match] = []
  
    // Ya que tenemos el diccinario, con las fechas,
    // iteramos nuevamente para guardar cada partido 
    // en el diccionario y agruparlo con los otros partidos en
    // la misma fecha.
    for (let i = 0; i < matchs.length; ++i) {
        let match = matchs[i];
        matchsDictionary[match.date_match].push(match)
    }

    // Object.hasOwn puede utilizarse para no iterar dos veces
    // pero algunos navegadores no lo soportan.
    
    return (
       <div>
          <h1 className=''>Match List</h1>
            {
              Object.keys(matchsDictionary).map((match_date) => (
                <div>
                  <h1>{match_date}</h1>
                  matchsDictionary[match_date].map((m) => (
                    <Match key={m.id} matchDetails={m} />
                  ))
                </div>
              ))
            }
       </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Maestro, Sensei, muchas gracias. Tu respuesta funcionó, arrojó el resultado que quería. Todos los días se aprende algo nuevo. 